# Excel converts to Time Format

Tags: excel, office365

Excel is converting any number it seems to a time format, which of course I don't want. Even if I create a new pivot chart.

`For example I have a dataset with about 5 rows, each of which has a student ID. If I create a pivot, I want the new pivot to begin with "count of student ID."`

However, I see `01/15/1915 12:00:00`. When I convert the sheet to general (or any valid format) I get what I want, which is `5494`. When I create the pivot and click on a cell, I should get the data of number of students behind that number. **But then the data that comes up also needs to be converted**. I have no idea why this is happening. And yes, I have tried reformatting the original data.

I think this is a bug or setting in Excel.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Excel.  There was an old bug in 2007 where the `Normal` style would spontaneously change under ill-defined conditions.  Don't know if it has been fixed.  If that is the case, navigate to `Home` --> `Styles` --> click on the dropdown arrow and right click on `Normal` --> `Modify` and see what the number format is.  If it is not `General`, then click on `Format` and correct it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I created a workbook  a number of years ago with many formulas and VBA.  Just recently started having this issue!  I noticed that every new sheet I make is automatically defined as TIME.  I went to home>>number, and saw the format for a completely blank, new sheet is Time.

Comment: I am using Excel for Office 365, 32 bit version

Comment: I guess it hasn't been fixed.  What happened when you changed the Number format for the `Normal` style to `General`?

Comment: sorry for the late response here.  I realized it was a setting that must have been corrupted or changed by me without knowing when.  Anyway, on home menu, on styles, right click "normal" and select modify.  Then change the format to whatever you want.  For me, every time Excel created a new sheet, it was by default set to time.  I changed it back to general.  Like you mentioned above.  It was Excel 2016.  I had some difficulty finding how to get to the menu above in the picture.  But, this is how i did it.  And it worked.  Save many tissues from the tears I would have shed.